# How to make menu button removeClass for two levels of unordered list?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to solve an issue with my mobile menu, where if the user closes a child submenu using the toggle buttons, all of the subordinate levels of the menu (grandchild submenus) currently remain open when the submenu is reopened.

I am trying to make it so that by clicking the `ul ul`submenu button to close the child menu, it removes the `.open` class for the `ul ul ul` grandchild submenu as well.

The problem seems to be that I am unable to give the submenu buttons an id or class, due to the way that I have used the jQuery to insert them. Therefore I am unable to tell each level of submenu buttons which level of the menu to target.

I have tried to achieve this using a combination of the `.children()` and `.find()` selectors, but haven't had any success. Can anyone tell me the correct way in which I could do this?

**Note:** *I have used PHP to configure the menu structure via Wordpress, so I have little control over the html*

https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/44/

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="main-menu" id="mobile">
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-header-menu-1" class="menu">
            <li class="hide-desktop menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1386"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-463"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/">Link 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-584"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/landscapes/">Child-link 1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-473"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/seascapes/">Child-link 2</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-478"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/macro/">Child-link 3</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-477"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/cities/">Child-link 4</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-475"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/long-exposure/">Child-link 5</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                             <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-480"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/miscellaneous/">Grandchild-link 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-10"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/about/">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/shop/">Link 4</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/contact/">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav.main-menu#mobile {
  min-width:300px;
  max-width:400px;
  background-color:orange;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul { 
    position:relative; 
    overflow: auto; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul li {
    display:inline-block; 
    float:left; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding:15px 0px 15px 30px;
    font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:purple;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.submenu-button {
  cursor:pointer;
  float:right;
  padding:15px 20px 15px 20px;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul {
  max-height:0;
  width:100%;
  transition: all 800ms;
  background-color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul.open { 
  max-height:1000px;
  background-color:green;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li {
  transition:2s;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition:2s;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li.open a {
  color:yellow;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul {
  background-color:white;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul.open {
  background-color:green;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left:60px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
$('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>').insertBefore('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li:not(.hide-mobile) ul').parent('li');

$('.submenu-button').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open').children('li').toggleClass('open');
   // $('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li').next().toggleClass('open').children('li').toggleClass('open');
```

});

});

**Updated JQuery:**

$('.submenu-button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('open').children('li').toggleClass('open').find('li,ul').removeClass('open');

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/45/) to do this which seems to fix things for me (in that jsfiddle). I remove the 'open' class from all child 'ul' elements

`$(this).next().toggleClass('open').children('li').toggleClass('open').find('ul').removeClass('open');`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working! One thing I don't understand though and was hoping you could explain, is why this `removeClass` function doesn't cancel out the `toggleClass` function that opens the `ul` menu in the first place?

Comment: this is a form of programming called 'currying' where actions are executed in the chain they are presented. first we get the value of next() and toggle the class 'open' on it, then we get it's children 'li' elements and toggle the class 'open' on them, then for each of those 'li' elements we find all of their child 'ul' elements and remove the class on just the new set of children 'ul' elements

Comment: I see, thank you for your help and the explanation :)

Comment: of course, good luck. it's easiest for me to keep in mind that there are 'set creation' functions like find, children, filter and add - then there are 'set modification' functions like CSS, text, HTML and detach. set creation functions change the array of elements you're operating on

Comment: fwiw this _should_ do all levels below

Comment: I've just noticed a little bug that this has caused – I omitted this from the original code I posted above because I didn't think it was relevant, but I've added an `.open` class to the submenu button itself when clicked to indicate that the menu is open ( the plus sign tilts to the right to become an "X"). Now when I close the child menu and open it again, the grandchild menu submenu button doesn't revert back to a plus sign. Do you know how I could solve this? Here's a demonstration of what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/46/

Comment: I've tried using `removeClass` on the submenu button span, but this prevents the class being added to begin with.

Comment: in my jsfiddle, I mistakenly added 'li,ul' I believe you want just 'ul', I can't test right now I'm on a phone

Comment: Hmm, this didn't affect the `toggleClass` on the submenu buttons. I've had this problem before a few times where `removeClass` clashes with `toggleClass`and things start happening in reverse.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/47/ does this exhibit the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: cool, in case you don't know the ',' in a jquery selector is an or operator